# In Java, should the int value of a character be referred to as its ASCII value or Unicode value

Tags: java, unicode, ascii

I am working on a program in Java that only deals with capital letters.  During some processing, I am using the `int` value of chars of these capital letters.  I understand that the value of the capital letters are the same in Unicode and ASCII, but when referring to these `int` values, should I be saying that they are the Unicode values or the ASCII values?  I just want to make sure that I'm using the correct terminology in terms of the language.

Answer (score 2):

It should be referred to as a Unicode code unit.  A Java `char` is a 16-bit Unicode code unit, as opposed to a 32-bit Unicode code point (it was originally thought that Unicode would be 16-bit).  It will *always* take 16 bits, regardless of what the value is.  ASCII is 7-bit (8 if you consider the 0 padding/error-checking bit).  Thus, the term doesn't fully apply even if the actual value is the same.

Answer (score 1):

If the characters will only ever be ASCII, you can refer to them as ASCII. Otherwise, you should use the term Unicode which, as you state, is a proper superset of ASCII. Keep in mind that, even though you *refer* to them as ASCII, the *encoding* may need to be changed if you're sending them to something that expects real (octet-based) ASCII.

If you're software only handles code points in the ASCII range (and see below, this is not usually a good idea), it's much easier to say (to users, or in the documentation) "ASCII values" than "Unicode values in the ASCII range" :-)

It's actually *misleading* to refer to your values as Unicode code points in the context of doing things to uppercase letters, if you only handle the uppercase letters in the ASCII range.

Any new software nowadays should be written with Unicode in mind, and that *includes* the fact the uppercase letters are not restricted to the ASCII range.

For example, there's a chunk of Greek characters nowhere *near* the ASCII range that have upper and lowercase properties. The [`SpecialCasing.txt`](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/SpecialCasing.txt) file shows these properties and there's also a [FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html) on the subject.

Comment: Superset.  Also, I think this is misleading, since even when it's in the ASCII range it will take 16 bits.

Comment: @Matthew, yes, sorry, got it the wrong way around. But I would still tend to distinguish between the _encoding_ of the characters and their "code points" or meaning, no different from the distinction between "Unicode" and "UTF8/UCS2/UTF-32/etc". Saying that it's misleading because it's 16 bits wide is no different from when it's 8 bits wide: nobody complains that the 7-bit ASCII values are being stored in a byte :-) If the _values_ are 0 thru 127 only, you can refer to it as ASCII regardless of width - you'll just need to trim it down to size when talking to a non-Unicode environment.

Comment: Your computer does not use ascii. It probably uses iso-8859-1 if its linux or unix, and cp1251 if its windows.

Comment: Yes and, if I only use the lower half of those code pages, I'll refer to it as ASCII :-)

Answer (score 0):

The correct and proper term according [the *Unicode Glossary*](http://unicode.org/glossary/) for the numeric code is its ***code point***. For example:

- The code point for `DIGIT ONE` is 31<sub>16</sub> (49<sub>10</sub>), normally written U+0031.
- The code point for `POUND SIGN` is U+00A3
- The code point for `LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH DIAERESIS` is U+00EF.
- The code point for `GREEK SMALL LETTER MU` is U+03BC.
- The code point for `LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH DOT ABOVE` is U+1E1F.
- The code point for  `REPLACEMENT CHARACTER` is U+FFFD.
- The code point for `MUSICAL SYMBOL DOUBLE FLAT` is U+1D12B.
- The code point for `MATHEMATICAL ITALIC CAPITAL R` is U+1D445.
- The code point for `EXTRATERRESTRIAL ALIEN` is U+1F47D.
- U+100002 is an assigned code point in  the `Supplementary_Private_Use_Area_B` block.
- The assigned name of code point U+0041 is `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A`.
- The assigned name of code point U+1F47E is `ALIEN MONSTER`.
- Code point U+0FFE is unassigned, and so has no name.

And so on and so forth.